Binding Angular route params to computed signals
I'm trying to make my code as reactive as possible, switching from explicit route subscription to withcomponentinputbinding.
export class CustomerProfileComponent {
  private readonly oms = inject(OMSService);
  private readonly route = inject(ActivatedRoute);

  id = input<number>();

  // this works but isn't using the mapped input signal
  customer = toSignal(
    this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => this.oms.getCustomer(Number(params['id'])))
    )
  );

  // this doesn't work because getCustomer returns an Observable. 
  // Adding toSignal() doesn't work either, due to the context, but  
  // looking for something like this!
  xcustomer = computed(() => this.oms.getCustomer(this.id()));
  
}

If I call using route http://localhost:4200/#/customers/12 it will show the output from {{ id() }} as 12 as described by the mapped route, so I know that's working. But the xcustomer computed value doesn't get resolved and is output as:
{ "source": { "source": { "source": {} } } }
The service call signature is:
getCustomer(id?: number): Observable<Customer>

Is there a way to use the InputSignal that is bound from the route as a computed source in this way?  Using Angular 18.2.11.
UPDATE:
If I set a default value to the id, the customer signal is updated. But it is not triggered when using withComponentInputBinding(). I can only presume that the route update does not occur within the context that the signal update requires.
  id = input<number>(12);

  // This is triggered to update with the value 12
  customer = toSignal(this.oms.getCustomer(this.id()));

But without the default value, the id that is being bound to the route does not trigger the customer signal to update.
  id = input<number>();

  // This is not triggered to update
  customer = toSignal(this.oms.getCustomer(this.id()));

UPDATE 2:
Here's a minimal StackBlitz showing what I'm trying to achieve.

The best solution for this problem is to use resource from Angular 19 but since it's a lower version of angular. I recommend using two methods.

Using async pipe to access the computed observable data:
We can simply use async to access the data inside the observable, which is recalculated when needed by the compute, based on changes of the source signals inside.
Full Code:
import { Component, inject, input, computed } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../myservice.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [MyService],
  template: `
    <h1>Route Binding Test</h1>

    <div>
      Route bound id: {{ id() }}
    </div>

    <div>
      Customer: {{ customer() | async | json }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  myService = inject(MyService);

  id = input<number>();

  // How to make this a computed value so that it is reactive to changes in id?
  customer = computed(() => this.myService.getCustomer(this.id()));
}

Stackblitz Demo

Using effect:
You are using computed which returns an observable, but I guess you want to access the inner data without the observable. Then effect is the right choice, since it can access the data inside the inner observable and update a property  or a signal. Updating signals inside the effect will throw the error:

NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a computed or an effect by default. Use allowSignalWrites in the CreateEffectOptions to enable this inside effects.

To overcome this we can use untracked which does not track signal updates and get's rid of the error.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    {{id()}}<br/><br/>
    {{xcustomer | json}}<br/><br/>
    {{xcustomerSignal() | json}}
  `,
})
export class Child {
  private readonly oms = inject(OMSService);
  id = input<number>();
  xcustomer: any;
  xcustomerSignal = signal({});
  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      this.oms.getCustomer(this.id()).subscribe((xcustomer: any) => {
        this.xcustomer = xcustomer; // using property
        // untracked(() => {
        this.xcustomerSignal.set(xcustomer);
        // });
      });
    });
  }
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  input,
  computed,
  inject,
  Injectable,
  effect,
  signal,
  untracked,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  RouterModule,
  provideRouter,
  withComponentInputBinding,
} from '@angular/router';
import { of, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class OMSService {
  getCustomer(id: number | undefined) {
    return of({
      id,
      data: Math.random(),
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
        {{id()}}<br/><br/>
        {{xcustomer | json}}<br/><br/>
        {{xcustomerSignal() | json}}
      `,
})
export class Child {
  private readonly oms = inject(OMSService);
  id = input<number>();
  xcustomer: any;
  xcustomerSignal = signal({});
  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      this.oms.getCustomer(this.id()).subscribe((xcustomer: any) => {
        this.xcustomer = xcustomer; // using property
        // untracked(() => {
        this.xcustomerSignal.set(xcustomer);
        // });
      });
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child, RouterModule],
  template: `
    <a routerLink="/child/1">1</a> | 
    <a routerLink="/child/2">2</a><br/><br/><br/>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      [
        {
          path: 'child/:id',
          component: Child,
        },
      ],
      withComponentInputBinding()
    ),
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo

I have read that effect() should not be used when it would cause state change. I updated my post to better reflect what I'm trying to achieve and what works and doesn't work. Simply put, I want to bind the route field to a signal trigger.

@JensR. actually if it is mentioned in official documentation then I will accept, if not then I doubt the source legtimacy, anyway this is a simple way to handle the scenario, and untracked is used to overcome the effect() should not be used when it would cause state change which is the error I have mentioned in my answer

@JensR. also could you replicate the problem in the stackblitz I shared along with steps to replicate the issue? for debugging?

Simple StackBlitz project added to show what I'm trying to achieve

@JensR. is this the expected output stackblitz

That works. I got too hung up on using signals everywhere to get rid of any async or subscribes. I wonder if the new rxResource in Ng19 will be the ultimate fix.

@JensR. Yes exactly until then you can use effect or this solution. Will update my answer with the same

You could do something like this until a cleaner option is available.
customer = toSignal(
        toObservable(this.id).pipe(
          switchMap((id) => this.myService.getCustomer(id))
        )
      );

